# Expo WebRTC - evaluating 'WebRTCModule.enumerateDevices'

Tags: react-native, expo

Trying to access my camera, but not working when try.

```js
const startLocalStream = async () => {
  const isFrontCamera = true;
  const devices = await mediaDevices.enumerateDevices();

  const facing = isFrontCamera ? "front" : "environment";
  const videoSourceId = devices.find(
    (device) => device.kind === "videoinput" && device.facing === facing
  );
  const facingMode = isFrontCamera ? "user" : "environment";
  const constraints = {
    audio: true,
    video: {
      mandatory: {
        minWidth: 500,
        minHeight: 300,
        minFrameRate: 30,
      },
      facingMode,
      optional: videoSourceId ? [{ sourceId: videoSourceId }] : [],
    },
  };
  const newStream = await mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);
  setLocalStream(newStream);
};
```

When I trigger that function, it returns;

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'WebRTCModule.enumerateDevices')]
```

I use expo and I ejected react-native-webrtc.